# GhostScript PS to PDF conversion - No Color

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

Referring to this post, [GhostScript Conversion Font Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118133/3017105), is it safe to assume that **GhostScript's PS-to-PDF** conversions still do not guarantee cut-&-paste text from the converted document? Because I too am getting garbled copy-&-paste results with formatted documents, although it works with plain text files.

- [sample *Word* document .DOC](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=70666777916569853402)
- [printed to PostScript by MS PS Driver](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=84289624625948650570)
- [converted to PDF by GhostScript](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=91879982819345660521)

On the color issue, I am using the *Microsoft PS Class Driver* to print documents to PostScript format files, and then convert them to PDF format with the GhostScript v9.20 DLL *(sample source and outputs attached above)*. The options used are as follows:

```
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dSAFER
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-sColorConversionStrategy=/RGB
-dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB
```

However, it is converted without color. Have I missed some option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never guarantee getting a PDF file with text you can cut and paste from a PostScript program. There is no guarantee that there is any ToUnicode information in the PostScript program, and without that, if the font is subset as here, then there is no way to know what the Unicode code point for a given glyph is.

Regarding colour, the PostScript file you have supplied contains no colour, so its not Ghostscript, the problem is in the way you have produced the PostScript. At a guess you have used a Printer Definition (PPD file) which is for a monochrome printer.

You **might** be able to improve the text by playing with the options for downloading fonts, the basic problem is that your PostScript program doesn't contain the information we need to be able to construct a ToUnicode CMap. Without that we are forced to assume that the character codes are ASCII, and in your case, because the fonts are subset, they are not ASCII.

For some reason the content of your PostScript appears to be downloading the font as bitmaps. This is ugly, doesn't scale well, and might be the source of your inability to get ToUnicode data inserted. It may also be caused by the fonts you are using, you might try some standard system fonts (if you aren't already) like TimesNewRoman.

While its great that you supplied an example to look at, I'd suggest that in future you make the example smaller, **much** smaller.... There's really no need for 13 pages of multiply repeated content in this case. More content means it takes more time to decipher, try and keep example files to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

In short, it looks like both your problems are due to the way you are (or the application) generating the PostScript.

Comment: ,,, which might lead to the question why are you not installing a pdf printer instead of the double-complexity you are currently trying to get to work?

Comment: @StefanHegny That would be ultimate, but I do not wish to opt for a third-party product. Windows 10 has a built-in PDF print driver, but not earlier versions. It would be great if GhostScript had such a print driver, instead of beating around the bush with PostScript.

Comment: @KenS Thank you for another great explanation. I suspected as much but thought that the Microsoft PS Class driver would output color. After considering all options, I'd be more than happy to just be able to output a properly formatted image of the printout instead of fiddling with inaccurate PDFs. Pity GhostScript is not able to print to PDF or print to JPG.

Comment: One of my colleagues pointed out that the PostScript you have sent is designed for language level 1, a version of PostScript which was superseded some 25 years ago. Language level 1 PostScript had no colour support, and limited font support. In particular since it predates TrueType, no support for TT fonts, which is probably why you are getting bitmap fonts and no Unicode. We obviously don't know how you are creating the PostScript but you need to look at that as being your problem. Ghostscript can create both PDF and JPEG, but its **not** a Windows print driver.....

Comment: NB, the PostScript **is** created by the WIndows pscript5.dll (what you describe as the Microsoft PS Class driver), but that device driver is constrained by the capabilities of the device its printing to. If you are currently using something like an "Apple LaserWriter" PPD then I would suggest you pick something more up to date and try that, and HP printer with 'PS' in the name for example. FWIW the vast majority of the "PDF printer" products you see work by using Windows to create PostScript, and then a PostScript interpreter (most often Ghostscript) to create the PDF.

Comment: As always, thank you, KenS! Great stuff! Perhaps it's the driver files I'm using *(pscript5.dll, msxpsinc.ppd, ps5ui.dll, pscript.hlp, pscript.ntf)*. I thought that the *Microsoft PS Class Driver* was a good idea as it's bundled with Windows. I'll give it a try with a more current driver.

Comment: It (pscript5.dll) is the correct driver, but like I said, what it produces is modified by the capabilities of the printer it thinks its printing to. In this case it will be the 'msxpsinc' printer, I have no idea what that is. As I said, I would suggest that you install a PPD for a more recent printer, personally I have a number of 'virtual' printers installed, a couple of HP ones and a Xerox Phaser (I don't actually have any of the printers, I just use them to create PostScript). So I think if you install something recent to create the PostScript it will work much better.

Comment: OK so the msxpsinc.ppd is apparently the Microsoft XPS driver, I doubt that's what you are really using because that creates XPS files, not PostScript. Admittedly its probably somewhere in the pipeline if you are using Windows 10 because Windows 10 converts everything to XPS. In order to get PostScript output you must install a PostScript printer, and that's the PPD that gets used. As an example I'm using the Xerox Phaser 6120 PS and HP Laserjet 2300 Series PS printers and writing the output to FILE: Both of these work well.